# how to convert "/Date(-23788800000)/" to date "1969/04/01 00:00:00"

Tags: json, date

my current convert method as below:

```
function FormatDate(date, fmt) {
    var d = date;
    if (!d) return "";
    if ((Object.prototype.toString.call(d).match(/object\s(\w+)/)[1]).toLowerCase() != "date") {
        d = d.toString();
        var reg = /(Date\(\d+\))/ig;
        eval($.format("d = new {0};", d.match(reg)));
    }
    fmt = (fmt == null) ? "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss" : fmt;
    return fmt.replace("yyyy", PadStr(d.getFullYear(), 4, "0"))
              .replace("MM", PadStr(d.getMonth() + 1, 2, "0"))
              .replace("yy", PadStr(d.getYear() + 1, 2, "0"))
              .replace("dd", PadStr(d.getDate(), 2, "0"))
              .replace("hh", PadStr(d.getHours(), 2, "0"))
              .replace("mm", PadStr(d.getMinutes(), 2, "0"))
              .replace("ss", PadStr(d.getSeconds(), 2, "0"))
              .replace("{", "")
              .replace("}", "");
}
```

i want to convert /Date(-23788800000)/ to a string like '1969/04/01',
 can anyone give me some suggestions ?

Comment: What format is your input in?  Do you just have the integer -23788800000?  Is that supposed to be in Epoch time?

Comment: My input value is '/Date(-23788800000)/', it is return from server just like Json(DateTime.Now). Json() is a MVC serialize method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider an ASP.NET controller action that returns a date using JSON serialization:

```
public ActionResult GetDate()
{
    return Json(DateTime.Now, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

As you've noted, the JSON serialization will return a string like: `"\/Date(1398106878581)\/"`.

The number given is the date in milliseconds.  A simple way to parse that out in JavaScript is `var milliseconds = +json.match(/\d+/);`.  You can just throw that into a Date constructor and away you go.

Here's the full JS code that would consume the `GetDate()` action we wrote above:

```
var xmlHttp = null;
xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
        formatDate(xmlHttp.responseText);
    }
}
xmlHttp.open('GET', '/Home/GetDate', true);
xmlHttp.send(null);

var formatDate = function(json) {
    var milliseconds = +json.match(/\d+/);
    var date = new Date(milliseconds);

    var fmt = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss";
    var formatted = fmt.replace("yyyy", date.getFullYear())
              .replace("MM", date.getMonth() + 1)
              .replace("yy", date.getYear() + 1)
              .replace("dd", date.getDate())
              .replace("hh", date.getHours())
              .replace("mm", date.getMinutes())
              .replace("ss", date.getSeconds())
              .replace("{", "")
              .replace("}", "");
    return formatted;
}
```